# How to check database connection status?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, database-connection

What is the most elegant/practicable way to get the database connection state via fluent nhibernate? I know there is the possibility to check the up-state via SqlConnection class, but is there a way to use fluent nhibernate library?

Comment: probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916738/testing-connection-parameters-with-nhibernate) what you are looking for

Comment: @SergeyBoiko thanks, helped me a lot! if you put your comment to the answers I am willing to accept this as my answer of choice!

Comment: thank you very much, i really appreciate it, but I would prefer to avoid of duplicate the already existing answer on stackoverflow, as my aim on this site is not increasing my rate, I just like to help people, so, I think, in this case I helped you - and if it was helpful for you - I'm happy :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Most applications use connection pools.  Mine can be configured to check connections before checking them out of the pool (e.g. "SELECT 1" query execution).  I'd recommend using a pool that does this for you.  Keep it out of your code.

The issue is immaterial to fluent or ORM.  Same problem even if you don't use those.